# Restoring Application status

Tags: iphone

i am having 3 tabs one is catalog tab,cart tab,seetings tab.When i close my app and once again open it i want my app to be in the same tab and same screen previously when i closed.So how to achive this?Are there any API's for restoring application status.

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize data into a number of different formats. Check out "Archives and Serializations Programming Guide for Cocoa" on the iPhone Dev Centre.

You can serialize to a plist file, XML and SQLite.

Also, if you use Core Data, you get a lot of this built in.

Comment: There are many ways to do this - archivers, writing status to a file, NSUserDefaults. You can use any of these.